# accessing IIS website from android device - website not reachable

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019, android

I setup a virtual machine using VMWare with Windows Server 2019 installed. On this server I setup an IIS server. I added these bindings:

[image]

I also setup a bridged network so the VM and my surface are connected to the same network. Now I try to access the server using `http://roman-server:85/` on all computers connected to the same network. I found out, that iOS and Android are not able to resolve the machine's name so I used the IP address from my VM for this (`http://10.1.1.125:85/`).
Now comes the strange part. This works great with my iPhone, but when I use an android device (I tested multiple android devices) it says that the website is not reachable. I have no clue why android devices are not able to access the page.

I disabled the server's firewall completely so I'm sure that it cannot be the firewall. All devices are connected to the same WiFi network.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check network access from android to IIS by ping command? I thik android devices just can be in different subnet. Check subnet mask too.

Comment: I just discovered that when I ping (from my windows server) the IP from the android devices, there is no response. When I ping my iPhone I get an answer. So the server cannot find the android devices and vice versa. I'll check the subnet, thanks for the hint

Comment: Changing the subnet masks helped. This answer helped me a lot to understand how it works, since I'm not that good in networking: https://superuser.com/questions/667970/android-device-is-not-able-to-ping-my-laptop-on-same-network